# Nature of the mapping $\gamma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ and its solutions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, proof-verification, solution-verification

Start by supposing that $\gamma$ is defined as
$$
\gamma(n)=
\begin{cases}
(n+1)/2 & \text{if $n$ is odd},\\
n/2 & \text{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, the equation $\gamma(x)=n$ has exactly two solutions. (For example, $\gamma(x)=2$ has the solutions $x=3$ and $x=4$.)

The next problem is to define a mapping $\gamma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation $\gamma(x)=n$ has exactly three solutions. This isn't so bad:
$$
\gamma(n)=
\begin{cases}
(n+2)/3 & \text{if $n=1,4,7,\ldots$}\\
(n+1)/3 & \text{if $n=2,5,8,\ldots$}\\
n/2 & \text{if $n=3,6,9,\ldots$}
\end{cases}
$$
However, the next problem is to define a mapping $\gamma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the equation $\gamma(x)=n$ has exactly $n$ solutions. I came up with the following rather unsightly definition which works (I think), but surely there is a better way to do it? Here it is (**Edit: Fixed notational problem.**):
$$
\gamma(m)=
\begin{cases}
[m+(m-1)]/n & \text{if $m=[n-(n-1)], [n-(n-1)]+n,\ldots$}\\
[m+(m-2)]/n & \text{if $m=[n-(n-2)],[n-(n-2)]+n,\ldots$}\\
\quad\qquad\;\vdots & \quad\qquad\;\vdots\\
(m+1)/n & \text{if $m=n-1, (n-1)+n, (n-1)+2n,\ldots$}\\
m/n & \text{if $m=n,n+n, n+2n, \ldots$}
\end{cases}
$$
This can easily be verified for $m=5$ (where the mapping $\gamma$ is defined just as it is for $n=3$), but this is pretty ugly and unwieldy. My book gives the following:

---

**Book solution:** $\gamma(1)=1,\gamma(2)=\gamma(3)=2,\gamma(4)=\gamma(5)=\gamma(6)=3$, and so on. A formula is $\gamma(k)=n$ for
$$
\frac{n(n-1)}{2}<k\leq\frac{n(n+1)}{2},
$$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

First of all, is the book's solution correct? If so, how? I don't really get it.

Comment: I really didn't think about it, I just skimmed through your question and noticed that issue. The book's solution seems to be for a different problem than the one you're tackling. The book's solution describes a map $\gamma$ such that $\gamma(x)=n$ has exactly $n$ solutions, for all $n$ ($\gamma(x)=1$ has exactly one solution,$\gamma(x)=2$ has exactly two solutions, $\gamma(x)=3$ has exactly three solutions, ...).

Comment: @GitGud Hmm. Hopefully. Because that solution by the book doesn't make any sense whatsoever to me. But with my problem as corrected now (with the notational fix), everything is correct, right (i.e., my solution/definition works)?

Comment: Your solution appears to be a class of functions rather than a single one. For each choice of $n$, you produce a function that has $n$ solutions to every natural, but what they're asking is what Git Gud describes. The $n$ referenced in the equation to find solutions to is the same $n$ that's counting the number of solutions.

Comment: BTW, I can tell you're suffering from a lack of notation. You should make yourself familiar with $a \equiv_p b \ $  i.e. $a = b \mod p$, and also with $\lceil x \rceil$ i.e. the ceiling function. Expressions like $m = 3,3+n,3+2n,\ldots$ can be written as $m\equiv_n 3$, and your big function as it currently stands can be written as $\gamma_n(m)=\lceil\frac{m}{n}\rceil$. In any case, if you now see what the question is asking, I think your time would most profitably be spent trying to understand the book solution. Ignore the 'formula'; focus on how they define the function's values in sequence.

Comment: @G.H.Faust OK. I understand what they did now. How did they come up with that formula though? I see how it works, but I don't see how they came up with it.

Comment: To anyone who has studied Computability, it is certainly the obvious way to proceed. To those who haven't it's a little harder to say, but I guess it's just another way of thinking. However, now that you've encountered it, can you see how the same kind of method can solve the other question you just asked? If not, i'll post an answer to it.

Comment: @G.H.Faust Not really. A clear answer would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @G.H.Faust I think I *really* understand the book's solution now. Basically, they have a mapping $\gamma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by
$$
\gamma(x) = n,\qquad x\in\left(\frac{n(n-1)}{2},\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right]
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Correct? (I realized why and how they came to the originally given inequality now)

Comment: What you've written and what they have are precisely the same, just notated slightly differently. So yes. It's probably worth noting that their way is more standard, as intervals are usually assumed to be sections of the real line.